# Windows installer seems to change temporary path during installation

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action

I am working on a windows installer which uses the WIX toolset. I have built a number of custom actions to support the installation process.

During the process the installer stores some temporary information needed to rollback some custom actions. This information is stored in a temporary file.

During testing I found out that Windows Installer changes its temporary files path during a single installation, during the install phase the path seems different than when rolling back the installation because of an error.

What is best practise for this kind of issues (tempory files):

- Use %windir%\Temp
- Use own temporary folder and manage it myself
- Something else..

Comment: Is there an actual problem you are trying to solve? Or is this just a question about the internals of Windows Installer?

Comment: Both... I want to learn from it.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: No problem, asked for advice